# Selenium Java. Вывод конкретных несоответсвий в тексте в консоль

Tags: java, selenium, текст, compare

Стоит задача сравнить текст на странице с текстом из документа xlxs. 
Метод equals выдает итог на правильность текста в целом.
Однако было бы полезнее получить в консольи точное место (например, в тексте есть лишний пробел, которого не должно быть), где обнаружено несоответсвие. 
Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: разумеется, возможно. в любом случае покажите, что вы уже сделали

Comment: // checking body
    WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.id("body"));
    String actualBody = body.getText();
    String expectedBody = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(14).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
    if (actualBody.equals(expectedBody)) {
    } else {
     System.out.println("UK Body is NOT ok");
    }
    ;